# Is it possible in .Net to set integer enum to arbitrary value

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

For some reason the `HttpResponseMessageProperty` which I'm using to return specific HTTP response codes to a client uses a `HttpStatusCode` enumeration. This enumeration does not include 422, which is not included in the enum. Is there any way to set an enumeration using an integer since that's what it is under the covers?

Comment: Yes, simply cast the integer value, for example: `HttpStatusCode code = (HttpStatusCode)422;` No guarantees about how this may adversely affect your program. (for example, perhaps there is validation/checking/logic somewhere that expects it to be one of the named enum values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - internally an `enum` value is just an integer and you can "force" an enum value to have an invalid value and the CLR will continue on its merry way.

for example:

```
enum Foo {
   Bar = 1,
   Baz = 2
}

void Test() {
    Foo foo; // as Foo is a value-type and no initial value is set, its value is zero.
    Console.WriteLine( foo ); // will output "0" even though there is no enum member defined for that value

    Foo foo2 = (Foo)200;
    Console.WriteLine( foo2 ); // will output "200"
}
```

This is why, when working with enum values of unknown provenance, you should always handle the `default` case and handle appropriately:

```
public void DoSomethingWithEnum(Foo value) {
    switch( value ) {
        case Foo.Bar:
            // do something
            break;
        case Foo.Baz:
            // do something else
            break;
        default:
            // I like to throw this exception in this circumstance:
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException( "value", (int)value, typeof(Foo) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the point, but since you mention it, `throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("value", (int)value, typeof(Foo));` would more useful for debugging an invalid enum value.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast any number into an enum, given the enum has the same base structure(usually it is `int` :

```
response.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)422;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have any value you want (as long as it is in range of enum's base type wich usally is int):

```
HttpStatusCode value = (HttpStatusCode)422;
```